# Comparing proportions of parts between 3 groups

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, proportion

I'm trying to compare the effect of treatment on fruit size grades over a number of harvests (time groups).
I have applied 3 treatments (10ppm, 5ppm and control), each treatment had 3 replicas of 4 plants (12 plants per treatment, 36 in total). Each treatment was applied once (same day) and no other treatments were applied.
For each harvest date 25 fruit were sampled and their size was measured. Sizes were then divided into 5 size grades (<18, >18, >20, >22 and >25).
For each harvest I want to test whether treatment significantly changed the proportion of size grades between the 3 treatments.
If possible, I would like to show increase in size grade (i.e direction of effect) over time (harvest dates).
[image]

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

P.S I'm using R for analysis.

Comment: What is your sample size in each group?

Comment: The size grades can only be influenced by the current treatment or also by the previous treatments? What I mean is, if you are investigating the same trees, could there be some carry-over effect from previous treatments?

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: Take the three treatment groups on the first harvest grade. I understand that each one (T0, T05, T10) consists of 4 plants, but do we also know the number of fruit in each group (in addition to the proportion in each size grade)?

Comment: Yes, 25 fruit from each replica (4 plants) were tested for size and divided into size groups

Comment: Testing proportions in a mixed model is tricky, to say the least. It seems that you are focusing on proportions because that's how you're used to summarizing the data. Why not treat berry size grade (or ideally berry size, if you have it) as the DV? Then you're just looking at a treatment x time interaction.

Comment: Thanks @DavidB. I did that already. I have showed the efficacy of the treatment on size. I am trying to show we can increase fruit size to certain size groups as each group will receive significant price increase. I therefore want to show (statistically) the increase in grouping as well as just linear increase.

Comment: Is it important to show the increase in grouping over time then? If not, could you collapse across harvests?

Comment: The main reason for the harvest date is to show when the affect of the treatment takes place and advise the application timing needed. I can run a test per harvest (ANOVA maybe) and show results over time that way. I'm just not sure what the best fitting test will be.

Comment: I see. Then yes you're looking at a post-hoc test to see when the effect of treatment is largest. Probably just a bunch of regressions would do, so that your get an easily interpretable effect size. If you're have a specific size category you're interested in (eg. Larger than X), you could easily test for differences in proportions using logistic regressions.